# Combined assignment operator in a while loop condition in C

Tags: c, while-loop, infinite-loop, logical-operators, assignment-operator

I really have a hard time understanding how the following piece of code works:

```
int x = -2;

while ( --x > -10 && (x -= 2)) {
    printf ( " %d," , x ) ;
}
printf ( " %d" , x ) ;
```

---

```
output:   -5, -8, -11, -12
```

I mean I get what

```
while ( --x > -10)
```

---

```
output:  -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9, -10
```

and

```
while (x -= 2)
```

---

```
output: -> infinte loop
```

alone would do, but how do they work with the and operator?
I mean for "while (x -= 2)" the condition is only met when x = 2, so how can the while loop even end and not go infinite like it does when only "while (x -= 2)" is used?

Comment: `how can the while loop even end and not go infinite` - that's exactly what the `&&` operator handles in the original loop. Both expressions need to be true in order for the loop to continue. When either one of them is false, the loop terminates.

Comment: -2-2 = -4 which is non-zero and thus the while loop runs infinitely. In fact it should run infinitely for any positive odd number or any negative number.

Comment: "_the condition is only met when x = 2_": That is the only case where the condition is _not_ met.

Comment: @kiner_shah: That's not true for `x == 2` (which is the value stated at the bottom of the question).

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb, Yes, I mentioned positive odd numbers. `x == 2` is definitely not an odd number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is unnecessarily obfuscated...

You are right that `while ( x -= 2 )` would result in an infinite loop.

However, C has (what are known as) **short circuit operators**.

Thus in the expression `while ( --x > -10 && (x -= 2) )` the second term is only evaluated when the first term is true.

Therefore, while the first term `--x > -10` holds true, the second term `(x -= 2)` is also evaluated... once the first term becomes false, the second term is not evaluated, and the loop exits with just the single pre-decrement... resulting in the output you observe.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you start with -5 is quite obvious:

```
int x = -2;
while ( --x > -10 && (x -= 2)) {
```

`--x` turns `x` from -2 into -3.
`x -= 2` turns `x` from -3 into -5.

... and so it goes further: using `--x` and `x -= 2` you decrement again by 3, so you get values like -8 and -11. (When you reach -11, you already checked for "> -10", which was -9 at that moment)

Then, again you do `--x`, turning -11 into -12, but you jump out of the while loop and you print that new value again.

**Edit, more clarification:**

`x -= 2` means `x=x - 2`, it's not some kind of a check.

Comment: so for what value of x is `x -= 2` true? For me i would make sense if it is only true when `x = 2`. But as mentiont in a comment this is the only case where it is not true. But that makes no sense for me..?

Comment: Response to Edit: 
So this means `x -= 2` does not give a bolean which has to be true for the while loop to contiune? It only does affect the value of x when the checking of the while condition is done? So if it is like this, in which order are the operations in the while loop condition executed? Left to right or vice versa ? I seems to mee that first all the operations on x are done and then the value of that "new" x is used to do the check `x > -10`.

Comment: or asked in an another way: 
why is for `int x = 10; while ( --x > -16 && (x -= 5))`the end value of `x = 21` ? As x reaches 20 the condition for the while loop is not met, but still the `--x`is executed, but not `x -= 5`. So i don't understand why it is like this?

Comment: @riko It will always evaluate to true. The purpose of  `&&` is to not execute/evaluate the right operand at the last lap of the loop, nothing else. Similarly we can replace if statements with stuff like `x > -10 && foo();`, which is equivalent to `if(x > -10) foo();`.

Comment: The trick here is that C has **short circuit evaluation** - if the first term is false, the second term is not evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
int x = -2;

while ( --x > -10 && (x -= 2)) {
    printf ( " %d," , x ) ;
}
printf ( " %d" , x ) ;
```

Lets dry run the code and check the value of x as it run through the loop. Now, loop has two conditions to satisfy i.e. --x > -10 && (x -= 2). In the first condition, the value is decreased first then check for the condition i.e. (x = x - 1) > -10. The second condition is always decreased by 2 i.e. x = x - 2, hence will always be True.  Till the time both conditions are True, the loop will continue. As far as my knowledge is concerned, the second part will always be True. Initial value of x = -2,

```
 Value of x                 Output
```

---

```
In the first loop:
is --x > -10, (x -= 2)
   True      True
   x = -3, x = -5                 -5
In the sec loop:
is --x > -10, (x -= 2)
   True      True
   x = -6, x = -8                 -8
In the third loop:
is --x > -10, (x -= 2)
   True      True
   x = -9, x = -11                -11
In the fourth loop -> exits the while loop since x > -10:
is --x > -10, (x -= 2)
   False      True
   x = -12, x = -14              -12
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The test is purposely obfuscated. Here are the steps:

- `--x > -10` always decrements `x` and compares the resulting value to `-10`, breaking from the loop if `x` reaches -10 or below.
- if `x >= -10` from the previous test, `(x -= 2)` further decreases the value of `x` by 2 and tests whether the resulting value is non zero. The only value of `x` for which `(x -= 2)` is zero is `x = 2`. In the present case, `x` is always negative so this test is always true.

starting from `x = -2`, the iterations are:

- `--x`  -> `x = -3`, the comparison is true
  `(x -= 2)` -> `x = -5`, `printf` outputs `-5`
- `--x`  -> `x = -6`, the comparison is true
  `(x -= 2)` -> `x = -8`, `printf` outputs `-8`
- `--x`  -> `x = -9`, the comparison is true
  `(x -= 2)` -> `x = -11`, `printf` outputs `-11`
- `--x`  -> `x = -12`, the comparison is false, the loop is exited
- the final `printf` outputs `-12`

Answer (score -1):

This is some "obfuscate things just for the heck of it" algorithm, from which very little of value can be learnt, except "don't write crap like this".

What it does is to decrease the value by 3, but split that decrease in two steps. First always decrease by 1 and then by 2 more, unless it's the very last lap in the loop. So the `&&` serves two purposes: to only decrease by 1 the last time of the iteration, as well as a sequence point to allow two modifications of `x` in the same expression (which is very bad practice, `&&` or not).

For those not participating in the International Obfuscated C Code Contest, it might make more sense to rewrite the code similar to this:

```
int x;
for(x = -5; x >= -11; x -= 3)
{
  printf("%d, ", x);
}
printf("%d", x+2);
```

This is also nonsense code but at least it is readable. As a bonus, it also contains less branching than the obfuscated version.

Comment: I totally agree with you that this is nonsense code, but it is code from an exam I took in an engineering school (mechanical engineering). Hence the question. And thanks for the clear answer!

Comment: @riko Sounds like the kind of programming class that only serves to scare engineers away from software. I might be imagining things, but it seems common that out of tradition, those who aren't exclusively studying computer engineering get worse C beginner classes than those who do.

Comment: If a new hire could not figure out what this code did, would you want them to work on production code?

Comment: @EricPostpischil If a company showed me something like this on an interview question, would I like to work at that company?

Comment: The critical skill exercised by assignments like this is analyzing code for what it actually does rather than what one might think it does from a casual reading or a misleading comment or presentation. Another skill it teaches is following complicated code in detail. Certainly nobody ought to write confusing code, but it is undeniable that confusing code arises in practice whether wanted or not, and software engineers must be skilled at seeing what the code is actually doing. It is insufficient just to be able to read and work with easy-to-understand code.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Be that as it may, such code holds no place in beginner classes. This wasn't even a software engineering class but a beginner class for mechanical engineers. The main purpose of such classes is to give an insight in how engineers of other disciplines work rather than prepare one for a job as a professional programmer.

Comment: @Lundin: There is no assertion in the question tht this is for a beginner class. And anybody who works with code needs to be able to understand hard-to-understand code. That is just the way the world is.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Similarly, they must be able to rewrite such code into something better, one way is demonstrated in this answer. Often when doing so one might come to the conclusion that the algorithm didn't make much sense to begin with.

Comment: So now we see that your comment at the beginning of this answer is garbage. The exercise does in fact exercise a critical skill, it is false that “very little of value can be learnt” from it, and such exercises are an appropriate and necessary part of teaching. No student jumps from no knowledge of a subject to mastery without working through some tedious steps in between, and your opinion about the exercise is misplaced, ignorant of how humans learn, and disrespectful to students and teachers. It does not belong in the answer and makes it a bad answer.